# Shell Script to run command every 5secs for x number of secs

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm learning bash scripting and I want to call a function every 5 seconds for x number of seconds. The x is determined by the command line argument when the script was run. I've tried watch but it seems to go on forever, I don't seem to have an ability to return after x seconds. There might be a sleep way but it seems clumsy and I have to deal with local drift. Is there an elegant solution?

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then # only 1 command line arg allowed
   echo "Incorrect arguments"
   exit 1
elif ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then # arg must be digit
   echo "Argument must be a positive number"
   exit 1
fi

ask()
{
    OUTPUT=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c community server oib)
    CLEANOUTPUT="${OUTPUT:32}%"
    echo $CLEANOUTPUT
}

#export -f ask
#watch -n5 ask
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SECONDS` variable counts the number of seconds since `bash` was started:

```
#!/bin/bash

while (( SECONDS <= 20 ))
do
  echo "Running something"
  sleep 5 || break
done
echo "Done"
```

This simplistic method will `sleep 5` after the last run even when you know it'll go over 20 seconds, and it does not try to account for the run time of the command (if the command runs for 2 seconds, it'll end up starting up once every 7 seconds).

Comment: Why the  `sleep 5 || break`? Doesn't sleep return 0, so that break is never called? Even if it was called, what would it do, just before `done`?

Comment: `sleep` returns non-zero when killed/interrupted or when invoked with a time specifier that the current platform considers invalid, such as GNU's `0.5` or `1m`, or if the time variable ends up empty or wrong for some reason

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a little bit more accurate with the timing, you can put a `sleep` into the background, do whatever work is required, then use `wait`, which will halt foreground processing until the `sleep` exits. While accuracy won't be perfect, at least the time taken by the work part is not included.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOOPTIMES=3
REPEATEVERY=5   # seconds

for (( count=0 ; $count < $LOOPTIMES ; count++ ))
do
    /bin/sleep $REPEATEVERY &

    echo "Doing work $count..."
    # do whatever

    wait    # this will wait until the sleep exits
done
```

exit 0

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then # only 1 command line arg allowed
   echo "Incorrect arguments"
   exit 1
elif ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then # arg must be digit
   echo "Argument must be a positive number"
   exit 1
fi

iterations=$(($1/5))
for i in $(seq 1 $iterations);
do
      OUTPUT=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c community server oib)
      CLEANOUTPUT="${OUTPUT:32}%"
      echo $CLEANOUTPUT
      sleep 5
done
```

Comment: (I know sleep was not recommended, just thought I'd show you how I'd do it)

Comment: Sorry I didn't want it run for x number of times, I wanted it to run for x number of seconds. So if I put 20 in at the command line, it should run for 20 seconds, outputting every 5 seconds, so I'd get 4 outputs

Comment: Amended my answer.  As far as I know there's no way to stop watch from running after a certain number of iterations.